# Perl formatting issues in a script

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

for (my $i=0; $i<=500; $i++)
{
    print "Processing configuration $i...\n";
    system("g_dist -s pull.tpr -f conf${i}.gro -n index.ndx -o dist${i}.xvg < groups.txt &>/dev/null");
}
```

---

I have a system command which is needed to do formatting, so basically this command gives input files to Gromacs. My files are not like conf1.gro, conf2.gro, etc. They are like 0001conf1.gro, 0002conf2.gro, etc. So I wanted to edit this command like:

I tried using "%04d" since all the numbers are four-digit numbers, but I don't how to properly use zero-based here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is "magic", and can be used to increment strings like this:

```
for my $num ( '0001' .. '0010' ) {
    my $conf = "conf$num.gro";
    my $dist = "dist$num.xvg";
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit hacky, but it does the trick:

Insert the following line as the first line into your loop:

```
while (length($i) < 4) { $i = '0'.$i; }
```

The nicer way would incorporate http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html:

```
$cmd = sprintf('g_dist -s pull.tpr -f conf%1$04d.gro -n index.ndx -o dist%1$04d.xvg < groups.txt &>/dev/null', $i);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.

"conf%1$04d.gro" , in this thing , what's the meaning of 1 here.

Comment: Use the first parameter, i.e. we're using $i twice and we have tell sprintf that, see the linked page